# Understanding id-Ugs and id-Uds graph of a nMOSFET

Tags: mosfet, basic, semiconductors

[image]

<sub>I'm so sorry posting such a horrible-looking picture, but I really cannot found pictures similar to it online and/or in English! If you found one, please let me know and I'll replace it immediately!</sub>

The left graph is a i<sub>D</sub>-u<sub>GS</sub> profile of a nMOSFET, and the right one is its i<sub>D</sub>-u<sub>DS</sub>. As you can see, the cparabola on the left is extremely alike to the dashed curve on the right graph(that is, the curve marked "预夹断轨迹", which indicates the boundary between linear and saturation modes).

I guess there might be some relationship between the two curves. However, I cannot figure out on my own. I've tried to draw a 3D graph showing the relationship between i<sub>D</sub>, u<sub>GS</sub> and u<sub>DS</sub>, but failed, because I don't know any model about MOSFETs.

So is there any relationship between the two curves?

Comment: No, the dashed line in the right graph has **nothing do to** with the curve on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the first graph means: -

[image]

The slope is called gm and is forward transconductance i.e. what small change in drain current you get for a small change in gate voltage. This graph is derived with a fixed bias voltage across drain to source i.e. the FET is operating properly in its saturation region: -

[image]

Given that the dotted line in the 2nd picture arbitrarily marks the transition point from ohmic to saturation regions then the two curves are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a relationship between these two curves.

The first graph shows the drain current as a function of the gate-source voltage, which can be written as
$$
I_D = \frac \beta 2 (V_{GS}-V_T)^2
$$
The second graph shows the drain current as a function of the drain-source voltage with \$V_{GS}\$ as a parameter. The transition from linear to saturation is marked by a dashed curve.

Assuming a simple MOSFET model, the transition occurs at \$V_{dsat}=V_{GS}-V_T\$. The current at the transition is given by
$$
  I_{D,sat} = \frac \beta 2 (V_{GS} - V_T)^2 = \frac \beta 2 V_{dsat}^2
$$
Since the dashed parabola connects all the points that show \$I_{D,sat}\$ vs \$V_{dsat}\$, it's the same parabola as in the left picture just shifted to the left by \$V_T\$ since in the first graph the x-axis represents \$V_{GS}\$ while in the second graph \$V_{GS} - V_T\$.